# Extract paths to modified files except for deleted or renamed files

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, gitpython

I need to get the paths to the files that were changed in the last commit using GitPython.
I managed to do it this way:

```py
import os

from git import Repo


repo = Repo(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
commit = list(repo.iter_commits(max_count=1))[0]
files = commit.stats.files

for filepath in files:
   print(filepath)
```

But now I want to filter out those files that were deleted or renamed, and I'm a bit stuck with it. I would be grateful for any help, maybe someone has such an experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [iter_change_type](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=iter_change_type#git.diff.DiffIndex.iter_change_type):

```py
previous_commit = repo.commit('HEAD~1')

# Deleted
for diff_del in previous_commit.diff('HEAD').iter_change_type('D'):
    print(diff_del.a_path)

# Renamed
for diff_mv in previous_commit.diff('HEAD').iter_change_type('R'):
    print(diff_mv.a_path)

# Modified
for diff_mod in previous_commit.diff('HEAD').iter_change_type('M'):
    print(diff_mod.a_path)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This worked for me. And I just had a thought, maybe if the file was renamed and modified in one commit, then it is worth using `b_path` instead of `a_path`.