# GitPython: get rename files as deleted and added

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, gitpython

I need to get git diff files since specific commit using GitPython. As I understood I get renamed files using 'R' type . Is it possible to get the rename_from in the deleted lists and the rename_to in the added list?

I managed to do it this way:

```
commit = repo.commit(<commit_hash>)

# Deleted
for diff_del in commit.diff(commit.parents[0]).iter_change_type('D'):
    print(diff_del.a_path)

# Added
for diff_del in commit.diff(commit.parents[0]).iter_change_type('A'):
    print(diff_del.a_path)

# Renamed - No need, Files will be included in 'deleted' and 'added'
#for diff_mv in commit.diff(commit.parents[0]).iter_change_type('R'):
#    print(diff_mv.a_path)

# Modified
for diff_mod in commit.diff(commit.parents[0]).iter_change_type('M'):
    print(diff_mod.a_path)
```

I based on this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68422402/extract-paths-to-modified-files-except-for-deleted-or-renamed-files](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: No, that's what the `'R'` type is for.

Comment: If it follows the same implementaion of git, git does not care for files being renamed... it _ infers_ if a file was moved when diffing by checking which files are gone and which have popped up between the 2 commits being diffed (not in-between) _and_ seeing how different they are.... so, you might have a file movement in a commit without any changes and then modify the file from what is was in that commit above a certain threshold and to git it will be a removal of a file and addition of another _if diffing_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Tim Roberts, renamed files must appear in 'R' section. Therefore I did this workaround:

```
added = [diff.b_path for diff in changes.iter_change_type('A')]
deleted = [diff.a_path for diff in changes.iter_change_type('D')]
updated = [diff.a_path for diff in changes.iter_change_type('M')]

for diff in changes.iter_change_type('R'):
    deleted.append(diff.a_path)
    added.append(diff.b_path)
```